# Angular ViewChild Why Am I having Trouble Clearing Shopping Cart

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

Hello  I'm on the last part of my E-Commerce application which is the checkout component. Once the checkout is successful I want to clear the cart. I'm  able to get all items from in shopping cart, add to cart and delete specific item from cart based on id etc;.  But when I try to empty cart it's not working. I get an error "cannot reach properties of undefined (reading handleclearCart)".

I am using @ViewChild  in the Checkout component(parent) to execute handleclearCart from child component (Cart Component).  I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have tested the @ViewChild on another component which is also a child of the checkout component(cart-item) and it works fine but its not what I need.  The checkout out component is based off of the cart component. Once it is empty the checkout should also be empty. The only difference in the checkout, cart and cart-item component is that cart-item does not have a  tag. I have included a short snippet of my code. This the last piece needed for cart.
I can't figure out why its not working. I would appreciate any help in pointing me in the right direction.  I have been working on this for a couple of days.

cart component

```
handleClearCart(){
  this.cartService.clearCart();
    alert("Trying to Empty Cart From Cart");
    
  }
```

cart html

```
<div  *ngFor="let item of cartItems; let i = index">
 <app-cart-item #cartComponent [cartItem]="item"></app-cart-item>  
</div>
```

Cart Service

```
export class CartService {
  id: number;
  size="M";
  product: any;
  items: CartItem[] = [];
  
  cartUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/cart';
  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router, private 
  route: ActivatedRoute) {
    
 }

  getCartItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
     return this.http.get<CartItem[]>(cartUrl).pipe(
      map((result: any[]) => {
        let cartItems: CartItem[] =[];
        

        for(let item of result) {
            //cartItems =Object.assign({},cartItems,{size:  cartItems});
         
            cartItems.push( new CartItem(item.id, item.size, 
            item.product, item.imageUrl ));
            // 
   //localStorage.setItem('cartItems',JSON.stringify(cartItems));
            
  // sessionStorage.setItem('cartItems',JSON.stringify(cartItems)); 
          
       }
         
        return cartItems;
        
       })
     );

        
   }
 
        
    clearCart()  {
      
    this.items = [];
   // return this.items;   
    /*did't work either*/
   } 

}
```

checkout component

```
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {
   
   // @ViewChild(CartItemComponent) cartitemComponent: CartItemComponent
    @ViewChild(CartComponent) cartComponent: CartComponent
    
  @Input() product: CartItem;
  @Input() cartItem: CartItem;

  cartUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/cart';

  size;
  cartItems = [

   ];

   cartTotal = 0;
   itemTotal = 0;  
   shipping = 8.00;
   estimatedTax = 0;
   myValue: any;
  
   

    constructor(private msg: MessengerService, private route: 
     ActivatedRoute,   private router: Router,  private 
     cartService:CartService, private productService: ProductService) {}


    ngOnInit() {
        this.handleSubscription(); 
        this.loadCartItems();

    }
   
    handleSubscription(){

        this.msg.getMsg().subscribe((product: Product) => {   
         alert("loading cart items");
        })
   
       }

       loadCartItems(){

        this.cartService.getCartItems().subscribe((items:
        CartItem[]) =>    {
        this.cartItems = items;
        this.calcCartTotal();
         this.calNumberOfItems();
       })
      }

      calcCartTotal() {
      
       this.cartTotal = 0;
         this.cartItems.forEach(item => {
           this.cartTotal += (item.qty * item.price); 
           
         })

         this.cartTotal +=  this.shipping;
         this.myValue = this.cartTotal
         render(
          {
           id:"#paypal-button-container",
           currency: "USD",
           value: this.myValue,

           onApprove: (details) =>{
               alert("Transaction Suceessfull")
               console.log(this.myValue);
               this.cartComponent.handleClearCart();
              
               
           }
            
          } 
       );
       }
      
      calNumberOfItems(){
        console.log("Trying to get tolal items")
        this.itemTotal = 0;
        this.cartItems.forEach(item => {
        this.itemTotal += item.qty;
        })
       
       }

   
  }
```

checkout html

```
    <div  *ngFor="let item of cartItems; let i = index" ="height:20%; 
     width:20px;">
     <app-cart-item #cartitemComponent [cartItem]="item"></app-cart-item>  
   </div>
```

cartitem component

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'app-cart-item',
      templateUrl: './cart-item.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./cart-item.component.scss']
    })
    
    export class CartItemComponent implements OnInit {
    
      form: FormGroup; 
     
      @Input() cartItem: CartItem
    
      addProperty;
      Valuesize:string;
      cartItems = [];
    
    
      cartUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/cart';
    
    
    
      constructor(private cartService: CartService,private formBuilder: 
      FormBuilder) {}
    
      
      ngOnInit() {
    
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          sizeBy: ['', Validators.required]
    
      });
      }
    // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
    get f() { return this.form.controls; }
    
      handleRemoveFromCart(){
        alert("hit remove from cart");
        this.cartService.RemoveProductFromCart(this.cartItem.id).
        subscribe(() =>
        console.log("Product with Id deleted", this.cartItem.id),
        (err) => console.log(err)
        );
      
      }
    
       handleReload(){
        this.cartService.buttonClick()
        
        
      }
```

cartitem html

```
<div class="container-md" style="height:50%; width:150px;">
  <img class="img-fluid" [src]="cartItem.imageUrl" alt="Cart Item">     
    <div class="text-nowrap" style="font-size:13px; width: 400px"> 
   {{cartItem.productName}}</div> 
     {{cartItem?.size}}{{Valuesize}}
   
   <div style="font-size:13px"><strong>{{ (cartItem.price) | currency}} 
     </strong></div>
    <div class=" float-right">
     <span><i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can" style="color:#D30169; cursor: 
     pointer;  padding-bottom:20px; " 
      (click)="handleRemoveFromCart();handleReload()"></i></span>
   </div>
   
  </div>
```

Comment: `checkout.component.html` contains `app-cart-item` now `app-cart` component. So viewchild is `undefined` as expected, right?

Comment: Also, what is the reason behind calling the child component method from a parent, right then you can use`@Output` property. And emit and event when needs to trigger a function like `onClearCart.emit(data)`

Answer (score 0):

Instaed of use the NgOnInit lifecycle, you should use ngAfterViewInit

```
  ngOnInit() {
        this.handleSubscription(); 
        this.loadCartItems();
    }
```

.

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
         this.handleSubscription(); 
            this.loadCartItems();
}
```

the reason is because you are calling `this.loadCartItems();` on the OnInit method and loadCartItems call inside to `this.calcCartTotal();`
And calcCartTotal call inside   `this.cartComponent.handleClearCart()`

But, on the onInit Lifecycle, cartComponent in not defined yet